# The App menu bar has disappeared after upgrading to Android Studio 3.6.3

Tags: android, image-processing, menu, upgrade, visibility

After upgrading to Android Studio 3.6.1 the Menu Bar and all the Images in my app disappeared. I did not make any changes to these items. All the Images have become gray boxes.

This is the menu xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

This is the items

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_SelectByDate"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Select By Date" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="800"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_help"
    android:orderInCategory="900"
    android:title="@string/action_help"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

This is the app_bar_main XML layout:

```
   <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >

  <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        app:titleTextColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>



</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Activity Layout XML

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.DailyPicturesActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" />

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:tag="fragment_dailypicture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/my_nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
        app:defaultNavHost="true" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Here's a layout with images that look fine in the layout but show as gray boxes in the app

```
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btSaveImage"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="59dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/image_saved_Description"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btNextImage"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btNextImage"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btGoToHome"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_saved_to_disk_foreground" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btGoToHome"
            android:layout_width="63dp"
            android:layout_height="61dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/tx_return_to_home"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/btNextImage"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_home_blue_24dp" />
```

Here is a before 3.6 and after 3.6 screen shots of what the view looks like:
    [image]

Can anyone tell me what happen and how to fix?

Comment: Try to open errors and warnings in the design view using the top little yellow triangle (or hitting 'E') and examine them

Comment: Thanks Zain, There is a warning on both the app_menu_bar and the activity_daily_picture XML files. However it does not seam to point to my issue. It says

Comment: Thanks Zain, There is a warning on both the app_menu_bar and the activity_daily_picture XML files. However it does not seam to point to my issue. It says "The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate: 
- Paint.setLetterSpacing() not supported. (Ignore for this session)". This does not have a definitive fix that I can find. most text say ignore and depend on device rendering.

Comment: I guess you use a custom Toolbar instead of the ActionBar, can you check the styles.xml to have `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` theme

Comment: Yes Zain, I had forgotten that I have the following code                                                            

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

   Should I go back to the action bat?

Comment: Hi Zain, I added the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` to the style sheet no change. Going to move away from custom tool bar. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## Reply from Android Studio support as bug: No further information has been supplied at this time.

Reference Info: 156038688 The App menu bar has disappeared after upgrading to Android Studio 3.6.1
component:  Android Public Tracker > App Development > Android Studio > Configuration > Windows & Menus
    'status:  Assigned
    reporter:  p.....r@gmail.com
    assignee:  an...@google.com
    cc:  pa......r@gmail.com
    type:  Bug
    priority:  P3
    severity:  S3
    retention:  Component default`